# Display id data and Delete in DataTable Id Using ASP.NET MVC C# Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, datatables

I am a beginner so I have some troubles.

I want to display the data for the Id selected when I click delete in my data table.

In the view I created to Delete the Id the data does not appear, I try to do a variable in my HttpPost but I am not able to do it properly.

Any help would be really nice! Thanks!

Here is my code:

this is my View:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Delete</h3>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailId)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailId)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userName)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.userName)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.description)
        </dd>
        <dt>
    </dl>
    <div>
        <br /> <br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-actions no-color">

                <input onclick="DeleteConfirmation(event)" type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete" class="btn btn-default" />

                <script language="JavaScript">

                    function DeleteConfirmation(DeleteEmailId) {
                        if (!confirm('Are you sure that you want to delete this?')) {
                            DeleteEmailId.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                </script>

                <br /><br />
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to Email Data", "EmailData", "EmailTemplate")
            </div>

        }
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Delete (int EmailId)
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int EmailId, string userName, string title, string Email, string description)
{
        Deletevalue(EmailId);
        UpdateDataBase(EmailId, userName, title, Email, description);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("EmailData");
        };

        return View();
}
```

Comment: You want to pass model into method Delete(int EmailId, string userName, string title, string Email, string description), right?

Comment: yes. So this is the view when i selected deleted in one Id so i want to display the data of the id that i selected. so foe example  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userName) should display the username  i selected to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ You should declare a object class which is you want to pass into your view.

```
public class MyModel{
   public int EmailId{get;set;}
   public string userName{get;set;}
   public string title{get;set;}
   public string Email{get;set;}
   public string description{get;set;}
}
```

2/ Need to call this class at the Start Controller

```
public ActionResult Delete (int EmailId)
{
    MyModel thisModelPassToView = new MyModel {EmailId = 9999, userName = "jb", title = "Doctor", Email = "abc@gmail.com", description = "My Description"};

    return View(thisModelPassToView);
}
```

3/ Your View will look like this

```
@model MyModel <!-- You missing it, may be you need to include your namespace -->
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Delete</h3>
    <hr />

    <div>
        <br /> <br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<dl class="dl-horizontal">

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailId)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmailId)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userName)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.userName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userName)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.title)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.description)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.description)
        </dd>
        <dt>
    </dl>
            <div class="form-actions no-color">

                <input onclick="DeleteConfirmation(event)" type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete" class="btn btn-default" />

                <script language="JavaScript">

                    function DeleteConfirmation(DeleteEmailId) {
                        if (!confirm('Are you sure that you want to delete this?')) {
                            DeleteEmailId.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                </script>

                <br /><br />
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to Email Data", "EmailData", "EmailTemplate")
            </div>

        }
    </div>
</body>
```

4/ In your Post Method, you should declare like this.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete(MyModel modelPass)
{
        Deletevalue(modelPass.EmailId);
        UpdateDataBase(modelPass.EmailId, modelPass.userName, modelPass.title, modelPass.Email, modelPass.description);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("EmailData");
        };

        return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! but I have few problems when I try this.  The values of EmailId... Are from my database and should be the one i selected in the view so inn the action resul delete what should I put = to?  and another issue: If i put int EmailId in my model i have errors in other places that says can not convert int to string, i try to put int? EmailId but does not work i don't know hoy to cast it.

Comment: I edited in method Detete(int EmailId), in the case your EmailId can't cast to string let debug and view the state of EmailId

Comment: Also in   MyModel thisModelPassToView = new MyModel {EmailId = 9999, userName = "jb", title = "Doctor", Email = "abc@gmail.com", description = "My Description"};  the values should be the ones the user select and the data is in my database so how i do to be able to display it? thanks!

Comment: it work thanks,                                                                                                     but now in another action result i have an error when i display the data on the view. ` details.EmailId = ReadEmailData["ID"].ToString(); ` here i get an error that says that can not implicity convert type int to string. and i do not know how to solve it

Comment: thisModelPassToView just a example, you can replace it. At the point convert type, you can use: details.EmailId = Int32.Parse(ReadEmailData["ID"].ToString())

Comment: Ohh Thank  you so much!!!!! I was really stuck with it. One last detail i  need to solve. In de delete view it only display de id but not the rest of the data

Comment: I have the axtion result like this :  `public ActionResult Delete (int EmailId, string userName, string title, string Email, string description)
                                                                                                                                       {
            ModelTemplateEmail Deletedata = new ModelTemplateEmail { EmailId = EmailId, userName = userName, Email = Email, description= description, Title = title };
            return View(Deletedata);
        }  `

Comment: The reason why you only have EmailId at view because EmailId is interger and it have default value is 0, another is string and default is null. You don't have any real data to visible in view

Comment: oh i see so how i do to be able to see it in the view?

Comment: in the case you have a database, you can call data and map them to Model as my example.

Comment: what you mean as call data? i did as the example but it does not display the data. thanks!

Comment: let say you have string array data:string[] data = [["1", "jb", "Doctor"], ["2", "ab", "Director"], ["3", "cj", "Actor"]];. You only one to use first element for map to Model like my example: MyModel thisModelPassToView = new MyModel {EmailId = data [0][0], userName = data [0][1], title = data [0][2]};

Comment: Im so sorry but i do not get it(I am beginner). I don't understand the first part abourt the array data. So In my action result i have to add a string data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210365/discussion-between-maria-and-phong-nguyn).